# Python pandas apply function defined in class

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using Spyder IDE. I am trying to apply a self-compiled function ***sfill*** to my dataframe based on the different groups. Whenever I create this function, I get the following error:

> TypeError: sfill() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I am certain the function ***sfill()*** works correctly, when run standalone. What am I doing wrong? 
How do I allow Python to show the dataframe ***want*** without using statement ***global want*** in the variable explorer? How do I use return in this instant?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
have = pd.DataFrame({ \
"groups": pd.Series(["group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2"]) \
,"a0": pd.Series(["abc","1","something here","abc2","1","something here"]) \
,"a1": pd.Series(["","2","something here","","","something here"]) \
,"a2": pd.Series(["","3","something here","","3","something here"]) \
,"a3": pd.Series(["something","1","something here","something","1","something here"]) \
,"a4": pd.Series(["","2","something here","","2","something here"]) \
,"a5": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
,"a6": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
,"a7": pd.Series(["cdf","5","something here","mnop","5","something here"]) \
,"a8": pd.Series(["","6","something here","","6","something here"]) \
,"a9": pd.Series(["xyz","1","something here","xyz","1","something here"]) \
})

class main(object):
    def sfill(vector):
        vector = vector.copy()
        vector.i0, vector.i1 = vector.index[0], vector.index[1]
        vector.cond = have.loc[vector.i1].ne('') 
        vector.loc[vector.i0, vector.cond] = vector.loc[vector.i0, vector.cond].str.strip().replace('', None)
        return vector

    def Development_plan(selfdev):
        global want
        want=have.groupby('groups', group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(selfdev.sfill)



a=main()
a.Development_plan() # this is where the issue exists
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you coming from SAS land? You probably don't want to declare a global variable `want`. Look into making it a class variable or just returning the result from `Development_plan`

Comment: hahahaha! You are right. I am coming from SAS land. Still trying to get acquainted with python convention. 100% bored with SAS. i used return and got it working. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

functions in a class should take `self` as first argument

```
def sfill(self, vector):
    ...
```

when you call `selfdev.sfill(soemthing)` it actually calls `sfill(selfdev, something)`

`self` is only a naming convention, in your Development_plan() you use selfdev for this.

Comment: And just a minor addition. @Seb can also decorate `sfill` with `@staticmethod` if he wants to use it as regular function.